# Mongo C client loses connection with error

Tags: c, mongodb, driver

No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on 'mongodb:27017']

Why am I getting this error message? Thanks!

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Why do you think you're getting this error? If you suspect you coded it up incorrectly, post an MCVE, otherwise, drop the C tag. You've given no indication that this isn't a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) systems configuration question. While lots of things can cause connection refused failures, the first things that comes to mind is firewall configuration and authentication issues, non of which can be diagnosed without the appropriate logs and configuration files. Not a good SO question.